# How to reference tuples in Racket records?

Tags: scheme, racket, record

I'm new to Racket/Scheme (just learning it at my university) and I want to create a record named `flower` which has an attribute called `flower-coordinates` which should accept a touple or something like that, aka. x and y coordinates in the form `'(x y)`

I am using DrRacket with the language preset: "Beginner: custom" which seems to simplify the language itself. I hope anyone knows that.

I've written following lines of code up until now:

```racket
(define-record flower
  make-flower
  flower?
  (flower-name string)
  (flower-waterlevel natural)
  (flower-coordinates tuple))      ; <----- problem! 

(define new_flower (make-flower "Blubb" 50 '(23 12)))
```

`tuple` is not defined, which makes sense, since it does not exist in Racket but is there a way of how I could reference that here? As you might have noticed, I am a complete noob in Racket.

Comment: Racket uses [struct](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html) to define new record types. Where are you getting that `define-record` from?

Comment: There are many ways to represent Cartesian coordinates: complex numbers with the real part for x and imaginary part for y, an improper pair, a two element vector or list, a struct (the linked documentation shows an example)... (Oh, and it's spelled tuple and isn't a type in Racket or Scheme)

Comment: @Shawn (I've edited the question to make it more understandable) I have selected "Language: Beginner - Custom" in DrRacket. That's the preset our professor told us to use. I saw that it also removes the necessity to use #lang at the beginning of the program (aka. I have no idea, how these presets work)

Comment: Ah. I'm not familiar with any of the Racket student modes or language dialects.

Comment: What is "Language: Beginner"? Is it "How to Design Programs: Beginning Student", "Schreibe Dein Programm! Anfänger" or something entirely different?

Comment: Also, if this is homework, you should add exact instructions from your teacher. "a touple or something like that" can be a list, struct, or even another record.

Comment: Obvious would be abstraction. eg `(make-flower "Blubb" 50 (make-coordinate 23 12))`

Comment: I suspect that your language is something your professor has defined; it's not included in Racket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define-record` is provided by the `deinprogramm` teaching language (*Schreibe Dein Programm!*), so I guess your "Language: Beginner - Custom" is based on that. Try, whether your language provides [`list-of`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/deinprogramm/signatures-vanilla.html#%28form._%28%28lib._deinprogramm%2Fsdp%2Fprivate%2Fprimitives..rkt%29._list-of%29%29):

```
(define-record flower
  make-flower
  flower?
  (flower-name string)
  (flower-waterlevel natural)
  (flower-coordinates (list-of natural)))

(define new-flower (make-flower "Blubb" 50 (list 23 12)))
```

If your language is *Schreibe Dein Programm! - Anfänger* (or it doesn't provide `list-of`), you have to define a new record for coordinates:

```
(define-record coordinates
  make-coordinates
  coordinates?
  (x natural)
  (y natural))

(define-record flower
  make-flower
  flower?
  (flower-name string)
  (flower-waterlevel natural)
  (flower-coordinates coordinates))

(define new-flower (make-flower "Blubb" 50 (make-coordinates 23 12)))
```

Comment: I am actually studying in Germany and I'm surprised, that the teaching language is actually called deinprogramm, which is a German term  "list-of" isn't recognised, so I had to create a coordinate record. Thank you for the answer!